# magento 1.8 get taxes in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout-page, taxes

magento get taxes in checkout page

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml
```

by using this code i got tax_amount(total tax 10%+21%) but i need all taxes individually  by tax percent 10%, 21%... 
I have to display these taxes in checkout page

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount');
```

So Any help will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml  ---checkout page add the bellow code

```
$subtotal=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$quote = Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote();
$shippingAmount = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
$i=1;
foreach ($this->getTotal()->getFullInfo() as $info){
$rates = $info['rates']; 
foreach ($rates as $rate){
    if ($i==1){
        $amount2=($subtotal*$rate['percent'])/100;
        echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($amount2); 
    }
    if ($i==2){
        $amount1=($shippingAmount*$rate['percent'])/100;
        echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($amount1);
    }
  }
}
```